# Launch perl script under Windows from cygwin along with all child processes

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin

I need to invoke a perl script from cygwin but the script should be using the Windows perl and not cygwin perl.

```
# From Cygwin:
# This is correctly running under windows perl
cmd /c foo.pl

# foo's heirarchy
foo.pl
|--------> bar_1.pl
|--------> bar_2.pl
|--------> foobar/foobar.pl
```

As you see, foo.pl invokes a number of perl scripts internally. I want all of those to be run under Windows perl. What is happening is that foo.pl runs under Windows but all its children still run under cygwin perl. And unfortunately, I do not have the luxury of modifying foo.pl

So, how do I ensure that all the children perl scripts run under Windows perl? I know this is a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I figured I was taking the hard route by trying to make all the processes run under Windows. I came across this post [How can I modify my cygwin environment to use Strawberry Perl instead of the packaged Perl distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463947/how-can-i-modify-my-cygwin-environment-to-use-strawberry-perl-instead-of-the-pac) and by changing the PATH locally in my script, the problem got solved. All is well now :)

Comment: Changing your cygwin installation like this could be dangerous. Other cygwin tools could expect a real cygwin perl in /usr/bin/perl, and fail with Strawberry Perl. Maybe it would be better if you either change `$ENV{PATH}` to have the Strawberry bin path before `/usr/bin`, or to use `$^X` instead of `perl` when calling the scripts within `foo.pl`.

Comment: Thank you Slaven. I exactly ended up doing what you mentioned. I'll edit my answer.